# Which function is loaded first in custom class Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Which function is loaded first in custom class Swift? When I have a class that is linked to a view controller we have the viewdidload function.

But if you have a custom class? What is loaded than?

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class iap: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    override init(){
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "seemu.iap.test", "seemu.iap.removeads")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)

            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
}
```

I have this construction, but is this right? 
And there is an error on the request.delegate = self: 'self' used before super.init call. So I think the init method is not right for this case?

Comment: It is because you are using `self` before properly initialising it. In this case calling `super.init()` before `if` will suffice.

Comment: @VivekMolkar Okay, do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: add `super.init()` before `if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {` line in init method

Comment: @VivekMolkar Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider going through [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID221)